# Regular Expression for alphabets with spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I need help with regular expression. I need a expression which allows only alphabets with space for ex. college name.

I am using :

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\\s]+$/;
```

but it's not working.

Comment: The `\\s` in your regex should be simply `\s`.

Comment: 2 things you shouldn't forget: 1. Accept Petar's answer (and perhaps edit the * for a +; it matches empty string now.). 2. since this is labelled javascript, check the input on the server too; people can disable javascript and post anything to your server. Javascript checks are there to help the user with instant feedback *not* to protect your app from malformed input.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Just add the space to the [ ] :

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/;
```

Comment: have only space  characters will also be matched by this regular expression

Comment: but this will also accept field with only space without any alphabet, how to avoid this condition ?

Comment: use trim() function

Comment: this means the string passing through this can start with "a space". correct?

Comment: @PardeepJain, its accept `test dd 33` also.

Answer (score 35):

This is the better solution as it forces the input to start with an alphabetic character. The accepted answer is buggy as it does not force the input to start with an alphabetic character.

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+
```

Comment: At first look I felt having 2 groupings was redundant, but then realised your answer has the benefit of forcing the input to start with an alphabetic caracter. +1'ed. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

This will allow space between the characters and not allow numbers or special characters. It will also not allow the space at the start and end.

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+[a-zA-Z]$
```

Comment: If you want to validate the whole subject text, you should anchor it to `^`. And you may want to mention it won't allow a string consisting in only 1 letter. Also please use code formatting

Comment: This does allow spaces at the beginning of the line

Answer (score 5):

This will accept input with alphabets with spaces in between them but not only spaces. Also it works for taking single character inputs.

[a-zA-Z]+([\s][a-zA-Z]+)*

Comment: Did you try it? It doesn't accept space. But it matches `a;bb,cc:d.eee?f§gga`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Edited the answer with a little correction.

Comment: This is great b/c it only allows for single spaces, as we might want in a name.

Answer (score 2):

- Special Characters & digits Are Not Allowed.
- Spaces are only allowed between two words.
- Only one space is allowed between two words.
- Spaces at the start or at the end are consider to be invalid.
- Single word name is also valid : **^[a-zA-z]+([\s][a-zA-Z]+)*$**
- Single word name is in-valid : **^[a-zA-z]+([\s][a-zA-Z]+)+$**

Answer (score 2):

Regular expression starting with lower case or upper case alphabets but not with space and can have space in between the alphabets is following.

```
/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*$/
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work too,

it will accept only the letters and space without any symbols and numbers.

```
^[a-zA-z\s]+$
```

> ^ asserts position at start of the string Match a single character
> present in the list below [a-zA-z\s]
>
> - matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) a-z matches a single
>   character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case
>   sensitive) A-z matches a single character in the range between A
>   (index 65) and z (index 122) (case sensitive) \s matches any
>   whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v ]) $ asserts position
>   at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the
>   end of the string (if any)

Answer (score 2):

This one "^[a-zA-Z ]*$" is wrong because it allows space as a first character and also allows only space as a name.

This will work perfectly. It will not allow space as a first character.

```
pattern = "^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z ]*$"
```

Comment: This doesn't add an enhancement compared to previous answers. The original poster only asked for a regex to match characters, not to ignore leading spaces or strings that are only spaces

Comment: Thank you for your feedback but this regex enforces the common practice of not allowing spaces as the first character in a "college name" for better user experience.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
/[^a-zA-Z, ]/
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, simply type in javascript regex validation
/[A-Za-z ]/

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
function validate(text) {
  let reg = /^[A-Za-z ]+$/; // valid alphabet with space
  return reg.test(text);
}

console.log(validate('abcdef'));       //true
console.log(validate('abcdef xyz'));   //true
console.log(validate('abc def xyz'));  //true
console.log(validate('abcdef123'));    //false
console.log(validate('abcdef!.'));     //false
console.log(validate('abcdef@12 3'));  //false
```

Answer (score 0):

This will restrict space as first character

```
 FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*')),
```

Answer (score -2):

This will work for not allowing spaces at beginning and accepts characters, numbers, and special characters

```
/(^\w+)\s?/
```

Comment: OP provided `college name` as an example and your regex doesn't match the whole text, only the first word. This would also match `word @$%&/`, which it shouldn't