# regex to allow only alphabet,space & - only

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, regex

I am looking for regex to allow only (`alphabet`,`space` & `-`).

Tried below but fail in one of the case

1) Not allow space and - : `^[a-zA-Z]+$`
2) not allow single char : `^\S+[a-zA-Z -]+$`

Comment: another one also tried ^[a-zA-Z- '']+$ but initial accepting space as well.which i do not want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression for alphabets with spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289451/regular-expression-for-alphabets-with-spaces)

Comment: try this `var regex = /^[a-zA-Z -]+$/;`

Comment: Where is `-` allowed? Can it be in the beginning/end/multiple consecutive `-` allowed? Or really you do not want a space only at the string start (then use `^[a-zA-Z-][a-zA-Z -]*$`)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z\s-]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z -]*$");
```

Comment: var regex = new RegExp("^[ a-zA-Z -]*$"); try this

Answer (score 0):

Try below code only `alphabets` and `-` are allow . space is not allow on first time also. here is [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/c2x63wa1/)
if you want `alphabets` , `-` , `space` use this .  `var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z \b-]+$");`

```
 $('.onlyalphabets').on('keypress', function (e) {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        if (event.which === 32)
        { return false; }
        else {
            var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z\b-]+$");
            var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
            if (!regex.test(key)) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z\b-]+$");
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        if (!regex.test(key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: try this new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z\b-]+$")

Comment: @PUSHPENDRA SINGH  now check

Answer (score 0):

If you just do not want to allow a space at the start, and allow it and other chars you allow after it, and be able to match a 1-char string, use

```
^[a-zA-Z-][a-zA-Z -]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RRswdl/2)

The `^` matches string start position, `[a-zA-Z-]` only matches a letter or a `-` as the first char and `[a-zA-Z -]*` match 0+ chars from the allowed set up to the `$` end of string.

If you want to allow words separated with space/hyphen only, use [`^[A-Za-z]+(?:[ -][A-Za-z]+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/RRswdl/3).