# Allow spaces in a text field (regex)

Tags: javascript, regex

At the moment this prevents special characters from being entered in the textfield. I want to be able to enter spaces () but continue to disallow special characters.

```
function ffchecken(form) {
  var re = /^[a-z,A-Z,0-9]+$/i;
  if (!re.test(form.invoer.value)) {
    alert('Graag alleen letters invullen!');
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: `^(?:[a-z,A-Z,0-9]|&nbsp;)+$` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9289472/4229270

Comment: tried your suggestion but it doesnt works ;(

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add the whitespace symbol (_) in your regex ;)

So, it would be like

```
var re = /^[a-z,A-Z,0-9,_]+$/i;
```

Comment: Then use, like Cameron said, \s instead of _, so it looks like 

var re = /^[a-z,A-Z,0-9,\s]+$/i;

Answer (score 0):

do you tried `var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/;`. Please check.
For get Tab as valid, You have to use `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s ]*$/`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var re = /^[a-z,A-Z,0-9,\s]+$/i;
```

`\s` is the whitespace symbol. Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do a `contenteditable` `div` instead of a textfield?

```html
<div contenteditable>jou nederlands is 10 / 10</div>
```

It's basically the same as a textfield, just in here the html tags work.